# How to make the probability of a element being selected twice lower?

Tags: java, android, arrays, automation, appium

This code selects a random number from 1-27 and assigns that number to a index.

```
Random A = new Random();
int picture = A.nextInt(27);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='"+picture+"']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Lets say the code comes up with the number 8, how do I make it so that the probability of 8 being selected two times in a row is lower?

Comment: Would you like to make the probability  of selecting the same element lower but still allow it to be possible?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Create an int variable e.g lastChosen that keeps track of the last element.

```
Random A = new Random();
int picture = A.nextInt();
if(lastChosen == picture){
   picture = A.nextInt();
}
lastChosen = picture;
```

That reduces the chances of the same element being selected twice in a row from `1/n` to `1/(n^2)` where n is the amount of possible random digits you can get